# Callback to apply boundary json files - plotly dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to assign a checklist that allows a user to visualise json boundary files. I've got a scatterplot where the user to filter unique values in `Cat`. I'm aiming to achieve the same output but for plotting boundary files. Also, the scatter map box should start with **no** boundary files until the user selects one or more.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import json

gdf_poly = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
gdf_poly = gdf_poly.drop('name', axis = 1)

# subset African continent
Afr_gdf_area = gdf_poly[gdf_poly['continent'] == 'Africa'].reset_index(drop = True)

# subset European continent
Eur_gdf_area = gdf_poly[gdf_poly['continent'] == 'Europe'].reset_index(drop = True)

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Cat': ['t', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'f', 'f', 'j', 'k', 'k', 'k', 's', 's', 's', 's', 'f', 'j', 'k', 'f', 'j', 'k'],
    'LAT': [5, 5, 5, 6.2, 4.3, 5.7, 14, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8.5, 19, 15, 16, 18, 17, 15, 16, 7],
    'LON': [10, 10, 10, 11.1, 9.8, 11.4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8.8, 8, 15, 8, 17, 8, 6, 16, 7],
})


external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets, suppress_callback_exceptions = True)

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([html.Label('Cats', style = {'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
                 dcc.Checklist(
                     id = 'Cats',
                     options = [
                         {'label': 't', 'value': 't'},
                         {'label': 'y', 'value': 'y'},
                         {'label': 'f', 'value': 'f'},
                         {'label': 'j', 'value': 'j'},
                         {'label': 'k', 'value': 'k'},
                         {'label': 's', 'value': 's'},
                     ],
                     value = ['t', 'y', 'f', 'j', 'k', 's'],
                 ),
                 ], 
                 width = 2),
            
                html.Label('Polygon', style = {'paddingTop': '1rem'}),
                dcc.Checklist(
                    id = 'polygons',
                    options = [
                             {'label': 'Afr', 'value': 'Afr'},
                             {'label': 'Eur', 'value': 'Eur'},                          
                             ],
                    value = ['Afr', 'Eur'],
                    #clearable=True
                ),
                 dbc.Col([
                         html.Div(dcc.Graph(id = 'chart', style = {'height':800}))
                        ], width = 5)
    ])
], fluid = True)

df = data

@app.callback(
     Output('chart', 'figure'),
    [Input("Cats", "value"),
     Input("polygons", "value"),
    ],
    )

def scatter_chart(cats, polygon):

    dff = df[df['Cat'].isin(cats)]

    data = px.scatter_mapbox(data_frame = dff,
                             lat = 'LAT',
                             lon = 'LON',
                             color = 'Cat',
                             zoom = 1,
                             mapbox_style = 'carto-positron',
                             )

    if polygon == 'Afr':
    
        data.update_layout(mapbox={
            "layers": [
                {"source": json.loads(Afr_gdf_area.geometry.to_json()),
                    "below": "traces",
                    "type": "fill",
                    "color": "orange",
                    "opacity" : 0.1,
                    "line": {"width": 1}
                },
            ],
        })    

    elif polygon == 'Eur':
    
        data.update_layout(mapbox={
            "layers": [
                {"source": json.loads(Eur_gdf_area.geometry.to_json()),
                    "below": "traces",
                    "type": "fill",
                    "color": "purple",
                    "opacity" : 0.1,
                    "line": {"width": 0.2}
                },
            ],
        })    

    else:
        pass

    fig = go.Figure(data = data)

    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port = 8052)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code isn't drawing the boundaries, because of your checks using `polygon`:

```
if polygon == 'Afr':
  ...
elif polygon == 'Eur':
  ...
```

These conditions never evaluate to `True` since `polygon` refers to the `value` property of a `dcc.CheckList` which is always a list of things:

> value (list of strings | numbers | booleans; optional): The currently selected value.

https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/checklist

So you're doing comparisons like this `['Afr'] == 'Afr'`.

Since you indicate that:

> ...the scatter map box should start with no boundary files until the user selects one or more.

I recommend you set the default value of your `polygons` `dcc.CheckList` to an empty list:

```
dcc.Checklist(
    id="polygons",
    options=[
      {"label": "Afr", "value": "Afr"},
      {"label": "Eur", "value": "Eur"},
    ],
    value=[]
)
```

Then in your callback you can do something like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("chart", "figure"), 
    Input("Cats", "value"), 
    Input("polygons", "value")
)
def scatter_chart(cats, polygons):
    dff = df[df["Cat"].isin(cats)]

    data = px.scatter_mapbox(
        data_frame=dff,
        lat="LAT",
        lon="LON",
        color="Cat",
        zoom=1,
        mapbox_style="carto-positron",
    )

    polygon_mapping = {
        "Afr": {"area": Afr_gdf_area, "line-width": 1, "color": "orange"},
        "Eur": {"area": Eur_gdf_area, "line-width": 0.2, "color": "purple"},
    }

    layers = []
    for polygon in polygons:
        p = polygon_mapping[polygon]
        layers.append(
            {
                "source": json.loads(p["area"].geometry.to_json()),
                "below": "traces",
                "type": "fill",
                "color": p["color"],
                "opacity": 0.1,
                "line": {"width": p["line-width"]},
            }
        )

    data.update_layout(mapbox={"layers": layers})

    fig = go.Figure(data=data)

    return fig
```

In the code above I've replaced the if statements with a dictionary and a loop. For each selected boundary checkbox we add a layer to a list of layers and we use this list to update the mapbox layers of the figure.